# Last Insert ID is NULL in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the last insert ID like so:

```
$leadData = [
            'first_name'        => $first_name,    
            'last_name'         => $last_name,
            'phone_number'      => $phone_number,  
            'company'           => $company,     
            'email_address'     => $email_address, 
            'iso_code'          => $iso_code,     
            'product'           => $product,       
            'transaction_id'    => $transaction_id,
            'rep_name'          => $rep_name,
            'ip_address'        => $ip_address
        ];

        //insert lead into DB
        $lead = new Lead();
        $lead->create($leadData);
        //dd($lead);
        $leadId = $lead->id;
        dd($leadId);
```

but $leadId is NULL every time. My record is being inserted correctly into the MySQL table. Its a seemingly stupid problem, but has had me stumped for the last hour.

How could $leadID possibly be null?

Comment: Is the id in the table an auto-increment?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I first assumed it was because my 'id' column wasn't declared as fillable, but it seems auto increment columns are immune to this. See my answer below.

Comment: In case anyone else has this issue, $x->id only works if your primary key is named "id". I have a table in which the primary key is "note_id", thus I have to use $x->note_id.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had to first assign the return value of ->create() to a variable, and then use the ->id method as in my first example.

changing

```
$lead = new Lead();
$lead->create($leadData);
$leadId = $lead->id;
```

to

```
$lead = new Lead();
$result = $lead->create($leadData);
$leadId = $result->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep create object to one variable and print this print this variable object

```
//insert lead into DB
$lead = new Lead();
$lead->create($leadData);
//dd($lead);
$leadId = $lead->id;
dd($leadId);
```

to

```
$lead = new Lead();
$leadData = $lead->create($lead);
//dd($leadData);
$leadId = $leadData->id;
dd($leadId)
```